# Solution For to get iis Server Virtual directory path using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis

this local Web config file:

```
<add key="RK_Path" value="D:\\ScanDcocument\\Rk_Images"/>
```

i need to store some image to above folder, it is working fine in local machine path, but which is not working in IIS virtual path so can anyone suggest some idea to assign and access IIS Server D:folder
ex:

```
<add key="RK_Path" value="http://187.21.26.127/D:\\ScanDcocument\\Rk_Images"/>
```

so please provide solution

Comment: How do you try to save the files?

Comment: i am saving scanned image using configured path

Comment: if i am running in my machine which is saved fine, but in other machine IIS virtual path not able to save to other machine

Comment: How do you try to do it? From your browser? Some service?

Comment: i tried from my browser itself

Comment: i hosted in IIS(server machine), accessing from my machine could not able to access server D:drive physical path that's problem, how to assign physical path --is this correct or some other method is avialble  http://187.21.26.127/D:\\ScanDcocument\\Rk_Images

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Shared Folder on the Server, then you can access the folder by \MachineName(or IP)\MyFolder...

Comment: i shared too..but there is need server physical path, if assigned same D:path in local and server then i run the application and store the image but it is saved on my machine not in server that's is problem

Comment: there is need server D Drive physical path, for ex: csxi.writeif('http://187.21.26.127/D:\\ScanDcocument\\Rk_Images'), if i put csxi.write('D:\\ScanDcocument\\Rk_Images') means the data saved to local drive but need to save in server D drive

Comment: To make a shared folder is not a solution for an extranet applications. It's suitable for intranet.
To save files in server, need to use posting files (there are tons of examples on net).

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading files like described in the link bellow

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2